# Please synonymize [scope] into [allowed-topics]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

There are over 50 [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) questions on Meta, and it even states [in the excerpt](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/allowed-topics/info) that it is for discussing about **which topics are permitted / in scope on this site**. In comparison, [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) covers the exact same field (and is therefore synonymous), with far fewer questions (only 4).

Please synonymize them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Conquered!]

Not exactly "conquered", but... you know... [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).